How to create VM using ARM template in which image is referenced from Azure compute gallery?
The template below has been modified to use image from Azure compute gallery(ACG), eariler it used to reference the blob url of a vhd. Now, the requirement has been changed to create VM from image referenced from ACG. The ACG is in a different resource group and the VM which has to be created will be in a different resource group.
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "artifactsBaseUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "https://mypub.blob.core.windows.net/template-artifacts",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Base URL of the solution template",
        "artifactsBaseUrl": ""
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Azure cloud location for testing cluster"
      }
    },
    "clusterName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "testing cluster name used as prefix for host names"
      }
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Premium_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Premium_LRS",
        "Standard_LRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage account type"
      }
    },
    "adminUserName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "username used to administer testing (must be 'azure-user')"
      }
    },
    "authType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "password",
      "allowedValues": [
        "password",
        "sshPublicKey"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Authentication type for the virtual machines"
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password to login into testing cluster nodes"
      }
    },
    "adminSshPublicKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "OpenSSH public key used to login into testing cluster nodes as alternative to password"
      }
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_DS13_v2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "testing cluster node VM type"
      }
    },
    "vmCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 2,
      "maxValue": 100,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Number of nodes for testing cluster"
      }
    },
    "dataDisksProfile": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "min",
      "allowedValues": [
        "min",
        "min2"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Data disks configuration for each VM"
      }
    },
    "vnetNewOrExisting": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "new",
      "allowedValues": [
        "new",
        "existing"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies if a new or an existing virtual network should be used for deploying VMs"
      }
    },
    "vnetResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network Resource Group"
      }
    },
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network name"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressSpace": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network Address Prefix (i.e. CIDR)"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "subnet-ctest",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "all testing nodes will be deployed into this subnet within the Virtual Network"
      }
    },
    "subnetAddressSpace": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network subnet Address Prefix (i.e. CIDR)"
      }
    },
    "privateIPAllocationMethod": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "dynamic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "static",
        "dynamic"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies whether testing head's private IP address is statically or dynamically assigned"
      }
    },
    "privateIPAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.10",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Private IP address of the head node in the subnet, if statically assigned"
      }
    },
    "publicIPAddressNewOrExisting": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "new",
      "allowedValues": [
        "new",
        "existing",
        "none"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies if a new or an existing public IP should be used for deployment"
      }
    },
    "publicIPAddressResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Public IP resource group for cases when existing public IP is used"
      }
    },
    "publicIPAddressName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": { "description": "Public IP Address name" }
    },
    "publicIPAddressDomainNameLabel": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": { "description": "Public IP DNS label" }
    },
    "startUp": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "start",
      "allowedValues": [
        "start",
        "config",
        "none"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Cluster start-up type"
      }
    },
    "galleryName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "imgallery"   
    }, 
    "srcImageName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "someapp" 
    },
    "imageVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "1.0.1"   
    },
    "sourceGalleryResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "imgallery"   
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "preview": "",
    "storageAccountType": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]",
    "storageAccountNameStandard": "[toLower(take(replace(replace(concat(parameters('clusterName'),uniqueString(resourceGroup().name,parameters('clusterName'))),'-',''),'_',''),24))]",
    "storageAccountTypeStandard": "Standard_LRS",
    "imageId": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Compute/galleries/images/versions', parameters('galleryName'), parameters('srcImageName'), parameters('imageVersion'))]",
    "dataDiskSize_min": 128,
    "dataDisks_min": [
      {
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('dataDiskSize_min')]",
        "lun": 0,
        "caching": "None",
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "managedDisk": {
            "storageAccountType": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "dataDisks_min2": [
      {
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('dataDiskSize_min')]",
        "lun": 0,
        "caching": "None",
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "managedDisk": {
            "storageAccountType": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
        }
      },
      {
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('dataDiskSize_min')]",
        "lun": 1,
        "caching": "None",
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "managedDisk": {
            "storageAccountType": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "dataDisksConfig": "[variables(concat('dataDisks_', parameters('dataDisksProfile')))]",
    "hostName": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '-vm')]",
    "subdeploymentSuffix": "[uniqueString(deployment().name)]",
    "baseUrl": "[concat(parameters('artifactsBaseUrl'),'/')]",
    "startScriptName": "azure-ctest-san-start.sh",
    "startScriptUrl": "[concat(variables('baseUrl'),variables('startScriptName'))]",
    "templateUrlVnet": "[concat(variables('baseUrl'),'vnet-',parameters('vnetNewOrExisting'),'.json')]",
    "templateUrlPublicIP": "[concat(variables('baseUrl'),'publicIP-',parameters('publicIPAddressNewOrExisting'),'.json')]",
    "vnetID": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]",
    "subnetID": "[concat(variables('vnetID'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "sshKeyPath": "[concat('/home/',parameters('adminUserName'),'/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
    "linuxConfiguration_sshPublicKey": {
      "disablePasswordAuthentication": "true",
      "ssh": {
        "publicKeys": [
          {
            "path": "[variables('sshKeyPath')]",
            "keyData": "[parameters('adminSshPublicKey')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "linuxConfiguration_password": { },
    "linuxConfiguration": "[variables(concat('linuxConfiguration_',parameters('authType')))]",
    "computeApiVersion":  "2017-03-30",
    "networkApiVersion":  "2016-12-01",
    "storageApiVersion":  "2015-06-15",
    "resourceApiVersion": "2016-09-01"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('storageApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountNameStandard')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "ctestClusterName": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[variables('storageAccountTypeStandard')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "name": "[concat('ctest-vnet-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix'))]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('templateUrlVnet')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "location": {
            "value": "[parameters('location')]"
          },
          "clusterName": {
            "value": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
          },
          "vnetName": {
            "value": "[parameters('vnetName')]"
          },
          "vnetResourceGroup": {
            "value": "[parameters('vnetResourceGroup')]"
          },
          "vnetAddressSpace": {
            "value": "[parameters('vnetAddressSpace')]"
          },
          "subnetName": {
            "value": "[parameters('subnetName')]"
          },
          "subnetAddressSpace": {
            "value": "[parameters('subnetAddressSpace')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "name": "[concat('ctest-pubIP-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix'))]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('templateUrlPublicIP')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "location": {
            "value": "[parameters('location')]"
          },
          "clusterName": {
            "value": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
          },
          "publicIPAddressName": {
            "value": "[parameters('publicIPAddressName')]"
          },
          "publicIPAddressType": {
            "value": "Dynamic"
          },
          "publicIPAddressDomainNameLabel": {
            "value": "[toLower(parameters('publicIPAddressDomainNameLabel'))]"
          },
          "publicIPAddressResourceGroup": {
            "value": "[parameters('publicIPAddressResourceGroup')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('hostName'),'-nic0')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "ctestClusterName": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ctest-vnet-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ctest-pubIP-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ip1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "[parameters('privateIPAllocationMethod')]",
              "privateIPAddress": "[if(equals(parameters('privateIPAllocationMethod'), 'static'), parameters('privateIPAddress'), json('null'))]",
              "publicIPAddress": "[if(equals(reference(concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ctest-pubIP-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix')),'2015-01-01').outputs.publicIPProperties.value.id, ''), json('null'), reference(concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ctest-pubIP-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix')),'2015-01-01').outputs.publicIPProperties.value)]",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ctest-vnet-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix')),'2015-01-01').outputs.subnetID.value]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "enableAcceleratedNetworking": true
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat(variables('hostName'),'-0')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "ctestClusterName": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountNameStandard'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('hostName'), '-nic0')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(variables('hostName'),'-0')]",
          "adminUserName": "[parameters('adminUserName')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": "[variables('linuxConfiguration')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "id": "[variables('imageId')]"
            },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
            }
          },
          "dataDisks": "[variables('dataDisksConfig')]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat(variables('hostName'),'-nic0'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": "false",
            "storageUri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountNameStandard'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '-ss')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": {
          "ctestClusterName": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
        },
        "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ctest-vnet-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('hostName'), '-nic0')]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountNameStandard'))]"
        ],
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('vmSize')]",
            "tier": "Standard",
            "capacity": "[sub(parameters('vmCount'),1)]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "overprovision": "true",
            "upgradePolicy": {
                "mode": "Manual"
            },
            "virtualMachineProfile": {
                "osProfile": {
                  "computerNamePrefix": "[variables('hostName')]",
                  "adminUserName": "[parameters('adminUserName')]",
                  "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                  "linuxConfiguration": "[variables('linuxConfiguration')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "id": "[variables('imageId')]"
                    },
                  "osDisk": {
                    "createOption": "FromImage",
                    "managedDisk": {
                        "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
                    }
                  },
                  "dataDisks": "[variables('dataDisksConfig')]"
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                  "bootDiagnostics": {
                    "enabled": "false",
                    "storageUri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountNameStandard'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]"
                  }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '-nic')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "primary": "true",
                                "ipConfigurations": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '-ipconfig')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "subnet": {
                                                "id": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ctest-vnet-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix')),'2015-01-01').outputs.subnetID.value]"
                                            },
                                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "enableAcceleratedNetworking": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "extensionProfile": {
                  "extensions": [
                    {
                      "name": "ctest-setup",
                      "properties": {
                        "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
                        "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
                        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
                        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                        "settings": {
                          "fileUris": [
                            "[variables('startScriptUrl')]"
                          ],
                          "commandToExecute": "[concat('bash ',variables('startScriptName'),' ',reference(concat(variables('hostName'),'-nic0')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ',parameters('clusterName'),' ',parameters('vmCount'),' ',1 )]"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('hostName'),'-0','/ctest-setup-head')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('hostName'),'-0')]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/', parameters('clusterName'), '-ss')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
        "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3",
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "[variables('startScriptUrl')]"
          ],
          "commandToExecute": "[concat('bash ',variables('startScriptName'),' -s ',parameters('startUp'),' ',reference(concat(variables('hostName'),'-nic0')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ',parameters('clusterName'),' ',parameters('vmCount'),' ',0 )]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "fqdn": {
      "value": "[reference(concat('ctest-pubIP-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix'))).outputs.fqdn.value]",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sshCommand": {
      "value": "[concat('ssh ', parameters('adminUserName'), '@', reference(concat('ctest-pubIP-',variables('subdeploymentSuffix'))).outputs.fqdn.value)]",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "privateIP": {
      "value": "[reference(concat(variables('hostName'),'-nic0')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}


I have python script to deploy, which throws an error when I made the change
ERROR: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Id /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/imgallery/images/someapp/versions/1.0.1 is not a valid resource reference.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"},{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Id /subscriptions/fdedab26-abdc-4387-8176-012f6778d00d/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/imgallery/images/someapp/versions/1.0.1 is not a valid resource reference.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
azure call failed, return code: 1

As from the error it's clear that the path for the image version is not correct, so I created a vm from the same image version from the portal and on observing the deployment template (which gets automatically generated) found
"imageReference": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/imgallery/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/nliterepo/images/nlite/versions/1.0.1"
                },

If I replace the imageReference in the above template with this "id", get this error
ERROR: {'code': 'InvalidTemplateDeployment', 'message': "The template deployment 'testimg2-2024-08-20-11-57-29' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '5197dcc9-7acc-43e1-9a4d-cba9e5f9ad6f'. See inner errors for details."}

Inner Errors: 
{'code': 'InvalidParameter', 'target': 'imageReference.id', 'message': "Resource 'testimg2-vm-0' has invalid parameters. Details: The value of parameter imageReference.id is invalid."}
azure call failed, return code: 1



This ID must be of the form: /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/{imageName}

I have changed a little by using resourceId function
"imageId": "[resourceId(parameters('acgrg'), 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/images', parameters('galleryName'), parameters('srcImageName'))]",
but still throwing error
{'code': 'InvalidParameter', 'target': 'imageReference.id', 'message': "Resource 'testimg2-vm-0' has invalid parameters. Details: The value of parameter imageReference.id is invalid."}

Well the problem was with the apiVersion which I was using for the image from ACG. After I changed, it's working but now some other error for the VMSS, since the api version is changed.

@NaveenSharma I've already accepted it, please take a look. Thanks!

@NaveenSharma done!!

Here is the ARM template for creating a VM from an Azure Compute Gallery image.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "metadata": {
      "_generator": {
        "name": "bicep",
        "version": "0.16.2.56959",
        "templateHash": "14427937023370378081"
      }
    },
    "parameters": {
      "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "adminPassword": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "minLength": 12,
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "dnsLabelPrefix": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[toLower(format('{0}-{1}', parameters('vmName'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, parameters('vmName'))))]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIpName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "myPublicIP",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIPAllocationMethod": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Dynamic",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Dynamic",
          "Static"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Allocation method for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIpSku": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Basic",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Basic",
          "Standard"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "SKU for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "vmSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_D2s_v5",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Size of the virtual machine."
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
      },
      "vmName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "venkatgalleryimagetest",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name of the virtual machine."
        }
      },
      "securityType": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Standard",
          "TrustedLaunch"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Security Type of the Virtual Machine."
        }
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "storageAccountName": "[format('bootdiags{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "nicName": "myVMNic",
      "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "subnetName": "Subnet",
      "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "virtualNetworkName": "MyVNET",
      "networkSecurityGroupName": "default-NSG",
      "securityProfileJson": {
        "uefiSettings": {
          "secureBootEnabled": true,
          "vTpmEnabled": true
        },
        "securityType": "[parameters('securityType')]"
      },
      "extensionName": "GuestAttestation",
      "extensionPublisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Security.WindowsAttestation",
      "extensionVersion": "1.0",
      "maaTenantName": "GuestAttestation",
      "maaEndpoint": "[substring('emptyString', 0, 0)]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": "Storage"
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
        "name": "[parameters('publicIpName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "[parameters('publicIpSku')]"
        },
        "properties": {
          "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIPAllocationMethod')]",
          "dnsSettings": {
            "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
        "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "securityRules": [
            {
              "name": "default-allow-3389",
              "properties": {
                "priority": 1000,
                "access": "Allow",
                "direction": "Inbound",
                "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                "protocol": "Tcp",
                "sourcePortRange": "*",
                "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
        "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
            ]
          },
          "subnets": [
            {
              "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
              "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]",
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
        "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "name": "ipconfig1",
              "properties": {
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "publicIPAddress": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIpName'))]"
                },
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIpName'))]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
          },
          "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "id":"/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/VM_RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/venkatgallery/images/Venkatvmdefinition"
            },
            "osDisk": {
              "createOption": "FromImage",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
              }
            }
          },
          "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
              {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
              }
            ]
          },
          "securityProfile": "[if(equals(parameters('securityType'), 'TrustedLaunch'), variables('securityProfileJson'), null())]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "condition": "[and(equals(parameters('securityType'), 'TrustedLaunch'), and(equals(variables('securityProfileJson').uefiSettings.secureBootEnabled, true()), equals(variables('securityProfileJson').uefiSettings.vTpmEnabled, true())))]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
        "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('vmName'), variables('extensionName'))]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "publisher": "[variables('extensionPublisher')]",
          "type": "[variables('extensionName')]",
          "typeHandlerVersion": "[variables('extensionVersion')]",
          "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
          "enableAutomaticUpgrade": true,
          "settings": {
            "AttestationConfig": {
              "MaaSettings": {
                "maaEndpoint": "[variables('maaEndpoint')]",
                "maaTenantName": "[variables('maaTenantName')]"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "hostname": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIpName')), '2022-05-01').dnsSettings.fqdn]"
      }
    }
  }

Output:

Existing VM configuration

The VM has been created using the ARM template with an image reference from the Azure Compute Gallery.


Well the problem is fixed after changing the apiversion of computeApiVersion in json to 2024-03-01
